# Exclude Pingdom from Nginx Access Log

Tags: server, nginx, log

I am getting a lot of entries for pingdom in my Nginx access log

```
209.126.117.87 - - [25/Oct/2017:06:46:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14852 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
184.75.208.210 - - [25/Oct/2017:06:47:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14852 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
```

I am aware I could use in Nginx configuration:

```
map $http_user_agent $log_ua {

    ~Pingdom 0;

    default 1;
}
```

However, a malicious user could disguise his user agent as "Pingdom" and then all his traffic would go unnoticed. Is my understarding correct? Is there a more specific test I could use to exclude this kind of traffic from my logs?

Comment: Do you not use a firewall?

Comment: Yes i do, although I would think that's a separate process than logging access to my site ?

Comment: So you want to block it and log that block at the same time in nginx?

Comment: no I do not want to block it, I just want this not to appear in the access log :)